# WebAPI returns 404 (Not Found)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.0, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have created a simple Web API to return an HTML string from **domain/api/html/footer**:

```
public class htmlController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/html
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/html/section
    public string Get(string id)
    {
        if (id == "footer") return "<div>FOO</div>";
        return null;
    }
}
```

Untouched **WebApiConfig.cs**:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
}
```

I added the WebAPI to the **domain/api/** folder of a **domain** that includes a separate project (on its root folder).

Can it be that the WebAPI project expects to be in the root folder? If so, how can i fix it to work on the **/api/** folder? If not, what can be happening? (*Both **/api/html** and **/api/html/footer/** work fine when i run it from Visual Studio!*)

**EDIT:**

Can this be some IIS setting (i.e., it doesn't encounter an index.htm/default.aspx/etc page)? Navigating to **domain/api/** says not found right away, despite the **/api/** dir being there. Or perhaps in `Web.config`, most likely the `<system.webServer>` section, but the solutions offered (i.e, change path of *ExtensionlessUrlHandler* to `*` instead of `*.`) on SO, etc didn't work. In this example i gave, the server delivers a 500 error.

Comment: Based on what you are saying about adding it to `domain/api` then according to config your api is now configured for `domain/api/api/html/footer`. VS by default debugs on a root unless configured otherwise. If there are not going to be any normal MVC calls you could safely change the `routeTemplate` to `routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}/"`

Comment: Do you have an `index.htm/etc` in the `domain/api` folder? Does IIS see it if you do?

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the route path.

With this code you posted:

```
public class htmlController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/html
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/html/section
    public string Get(string id)
    {
        if (id == "footer") return "<div>FOO</div>";
        return null;
    }
}
```

You have these routes:
GET: `api/html`
GET: `api/html/id`

If you want some of this methods called from the route `api/html/footer`, you'll need to configure it. You can do something like:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/html")]
public class htmlController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/html
    [Route("footer")]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/html/section
    [Route("footer/{id}")]
    public string Get(string id)
    {
        if (id == "footer") return "<div>FOO</div>";
        return null;
    }
}
```

### Edit .Net 4

I have created the folders `domain/api` on the root of the project and added the controller the same way you did:

```
public class HtmlController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
    
    public string Get(string id)
    {
        if (id == "footer") return "<div>FOO</div>";
        return null;
    }
}
```

[image: Controller's folder]

And I'm using `.net framework 4`

[image]

Here's the result when I call `api/html/footer`:

[image: Result]

Have you created a `WebApiConfig` and added to your `Global.asax`?

```
public class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiWithAction",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new
            {
                id = RouteParameter.Optional,
                action = RouteParameter.Optional
            }
        );
    }
}

public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    }

    // ... the rest of your global.asax
}
```

Comment: I'm using MVC4 for .NET 4 framework, i don't have those attributes. I am confident that the problem is in `Web.config`, most likely the `<system.webServer>` section, but the solutions offered (i.e, change path of *ExtensionlessUrlHandler* to `*` instead of `*.`) on SO, etc didn't work. In this example i gave, the server delivers a 500 error.

Comment: I installed `AttributeRouting` package to be able to add the attributes you suggested, but still getting 404 error from server. It still works locally in VS.

Comment: I've created a project with .net 4 and it works as well. I've edited the post to show all i've done. I hope it will help you ;)

Comment: Can you please edit your answer so i can test it, i created ONLY the **/api/** folder inside the domain. (*http;//domain.com/api/*). Also the `WebApiConfig`is created and added to your *Global.asax*. I created a new Empty Web API project, that made all that automatically.

Comment: I think you are getting confused with the physical and route path. Its not because you have the folder /api that your controller will be called in that path (*http://domain.com/api/*). It will be called on that route because you have a configured route pointing to that url.

Comment: Yes i understand it. I can make it work LOCALLY when i run on VS, the problem is after it is deployed to IIS 8.0, Windows XP. I have other ASP websites there, all working fine. It's the Web API that don't work, most likely due to some `Web.config` issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you are saying about adding it to `domain/api` then according to config your api is now configured for `domain/api/api/html/footer`. VS by default debugs on a root unless configured otherwise.

If there are not going to be any normal MVC calls you could safely change the `routeTemplate` to `routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}/"`

Comment: I am only going to use WebService. I changed the routeTemplate for what you suggested, but it still gives 404 at `domain/api/html/footer`. However, still works using your suggestion running locally in VS.